# Mehler's Hermite Polynomial Formula for $|w|=1$ and applying the Dominated Convergence theorem to it

Tags: calculus, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

I only know proofs of the Mehler formula [see Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MehlersHermitePolynomialFormula.html) for the case $|w|<1$. In this [paper](http://www.fst.umac.mo/en/staff/documents/fstkik/FSKS07.pdf) (bottom of page 3), however, Mehler's formula is used for $|w|=\exp(-i\alpha)$. Moreover, they immediately proceed to exchange the integral with the limit of the series in Mehler's formula. If someone could explain both these steps to me, I'd be highly grateful, as I wish to do just these steps for my work, too.
  In particular, I'd like to justify this equation's first and last step, i.e. (a) Can I exchange integral and limit and (b) can I apply Mehler's formula: $$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\frac{H_{2n+1}(x)H_{2n}(0)}{(2n+1)!}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\frac{H_{2n}(x)H_{2n}(0)}{(2n)!}\\
=w\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^{n}\frac{H_{n}(x)H_{n}(0)}{n!}\\
=w\cdot(1-w^2)^{-\frac 1 2}e^{-x^2\frac{w^2}{1-w^2}}$$ for $$w=e^{ia}, a\in \mathbb{R}$$ 
And thus (?) $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\frac{H_{2n+1}(x)H_{2n}(0)}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{\sqrt[]{\pi}}{2}\mathrm{erf}(\frac{wx}{\sqrt{1-w^2}})$$
 I tested it numerically
 for some values of $x$ and it seems to hold.

Comment: At $|w|=1$, the sum still converges in the sense of distributions, and term-wise operators are still fine, in a distributional sense. Is this the sort of explanation you were wanting?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the particular problem I have in the question above. Maybe that makes it easier for explanations. I will have to look up convergence in the sense of distributions before I can tell whether this was the wanted explanation. But maybe you can relate it to my case?

Comment: Now that I've looked up convergence in the sense of distributions, I do not understand what you mean by "the sum still converges in the sense of distributions". In which way can I consider the sum to be a distribution?

Comment: Distributions do admit eigenfunction expansions under various hypotheses. Mehler's formula includes an expression for a Dirac delta and/or Green's function in such terms. A simpler case is that the periodic Dirac delta on the real line (a.k.a. "Dirac comb") has a Fourier expansion $\delta_{\mathbb Z}={1\over 2\pi}\sum_n 1\cdot e^{inx}$. This obviously does not converge pointwise, but does converge in the weak-* topology on distributions, or even in a Sobolev space. Similarly for Mehler's identity.

Comment: So if I integrate the sum along with some test function, I can say that, inside the integral, it converges to some other function? In other words, the final equation just by itself is not necessarilly correct? After all, that is my biggest concern.

Comment: This result is also referred to as the 'Mehler Kernel', and it's under that name you'll find it at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel

Comment: @Semiclassical Right, but I cannot tell from it whether it may also be used for my case, $|w|=1$.

Comment: @paulgarrett, Can you tell me if my calculations above are "allowed"? This is essentially the time evolution of a wave function and the results look very convenient, I am just a little annoyed that I cannot justify the equations...